# MVC 3/4 - Form data posted from paartial views and editor templates not reaching the Controller's action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an MVC 4 site that makes extensive use of partial views. On one page, however, I am using the the same partial view within nested partial views and my Model is nested as well. I checked it out in Fiddler, and the data is being posted as part of the form. When it hits my break point that I've set up in the action method of the controller those nested view models are coming in as null. I've tried using editor templates instead of partial views, but I had no luck on that one.

Has anyone experienced this behavior before, and is so, do you have any ideas as to what might be causing it?

Comment: It would be easier to help you, if we actually had some code to go by.

Comment: Try using Glimpse to get an idea of what's going on

Answer (score 1):

I have had this same problem before because I accidentally passed a nested ViewModel property into my partial page.

If you are nesting partials you need to be careful about how you are passing in your model, for example:

Lets say this is your ViewModel:

```
public class Person
{
public string Name {get; set;}
public Address Address {get; set;}
}

public class Address
{
public string Line1 {get; set;}
//etc
}
```

And your controller action:

```
public ActionResult UpdatePerson(Person p)
{
}
```

If you have a separate view to display an Address make sure you do it like this:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("Address", Model)
```

And not like this:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("Address", Model.Address)
```

If you do the second example the name of the "TextboxFor" inputs will be named incorrectly for the model binder to be able to understand.

Another option would be to call out address specifically in your controller action like this to allow the model binder to see the address properly:

```
public ActionResult UpdatePerson(Person p, Address addr)
{
}
```